# Error closing node-oracledb pool connections with Oracle DB and Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, node-oracledb

I have problems closing the connection to the database in Oracle.
First I create the connection without any problems.

```
  try {
  console.log('Initializing database module');

  await database.initialize();
  } catch (err) {
  console.error(err);

  process.exit(1); // Non-zero failure code
  }


async function initialize() {
  console.log(dbConfig.hrPool);
  const pool = await oracledb.createPool(dbConfig.hrPool);
}

module.exports.initialize = initialize;
```

when I want to close the connection, the application is waiting without answering anything, so I do it to end the connection

```
  try {
  console.log('Closing database module');
  console.log(" here 1");
  await database.close();// line  whit problem
  console.log(" here 2");
  } catch (err) {
  console.log('Encountered error', e);

  err = err || e;
  }

async function close() {
  await oracledb.getPool().close();
}

module.exports.close = close;
```

also note that I use a vpn connection for the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review `pool.close()` [documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#poolclose):

1. You probably want to specify a `drainTime` value otherwise the pool may not actually close.
2. You may need to add `DISABLE_OOB=ON` to a sqlnet.ora file

Comment: The second option was the one that worked for me, thank you very much!

Comment: When you have 19c client libraries & DB, this setting should not be explicitly needed: it will be determined automatically by Oracle